# Make class as observable in MobX

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have a class & I want to make the whole class as observable & then I am going to create the instance of that class & then it will be stored in the context, so before storing it I need that class as observable, so I can observe for any change:

```
class PrimitiveContext {
  currentPageId: number;
  primitiveValue: string = 'Testval';

  constructor(
    @inject(OBS_IT.CurrentPageId) currentPageId: number) {
    this.currentPageId = currentPageId;

    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.primitiveValue;
  }
}

// Context
const primitive = createContext(new PrimitiveContext())
```

Above is the sample code, how can I make PrimitiveContext as observable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/farwayer/mobx-decorators#allobservable
I use it in my projects, but it does't support mobx 5+ version